# highlight data on a matplotlib bar plot with an arrow

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to point to data points on a bar plot drawn with pandas dataframe and matplotlib.If I use a scatterplot ( replacing the categories in the data below with numerical data, plotting and highlighting with an arrow works perfectly) In the trivial example below the bar plot data are plotted if the conditional is not evoked, but'crashes' when running the conditional. I cannot figure out what the problem is. Help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
    %matplotlib inline
    bar_data = {'A':4,'B':8,'C':7,'D':1,'E':3,'F':9,'G':0,'H':4,'J':2,'K':8}
    bardf = pd.DataFrame(list(bar_data.items()),columns = ['x','y'])
    #display(bardf)
    bar_fig=bardf.plot.bar('x', 'y',figsize=(10,6))
    for index,row in bardf.iterrows():
           if row['y']==0:
                x=row['x']
                y=row['y']
                print(x,y)
                bar_fig.annotate(x,color='magenta', xy=(x, y), xytext=(x, 2),
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.3', fc='green', alpha=0.3),arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->',color='green'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solve your problem but instead of x that in your case is a char, you should use its position.

```
bar_fig=bardf.plot.bar('x', 'y',figsize=(10,6))
for index,row in bardf.iterrows():
   if row['y']==0:
        x=row['x']
        y=row['y']
        print(index)
        bar_fig.annotate(x,color='magenta', xy=(index, y), 
                         xytext=(index,2),bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.3',fc='green', alpha=0.3),arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->',color='green'))
```

Comment: This has resolved the issue. All instances of x have to be replaced with the index, which I missed. Thank you.